# Need help identifying these castle pieces

Tags: set-identification, castle

Wondering which set these castle pieces are from?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're likely from [King's Castle (70404)](http://brickset.com/sets/70404-1/King-s-Castle):

[image: set image]